# Autenticação customizada com Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

Como faço uma autenticação de login e senha customizada utilizando Spring Security?
O objetivo é verificar o login e senha no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Como você não deu detalhes não tem como dar uma resposta especifica então a resposta vai ser genérica, você vai ter que implementar a interface `AuthenticationProvider`

Exemplo:

```
@Component 
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override    
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

      String username = authentication.getName();    
      String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();    
      if ("user".equals(username) && "password".equals(password)) {    
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, Collections.emptyList());    
       } else {    
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed");    
       }    
    }

    @Override    
    public boolean supports(Class<?>aClass) {    
        return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);    
    }    
}
```

Fonte código: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-authentication

Mais referências: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider